# custom UITableViewCell Class dealloc not called

Tags: objective-c

this is the method

i have taken UIViewController type class and added all delegate and datasource in class and IBOutlet the tableView to XIB

in .h

```
IBOutlet UITableView *listView_;

@property (nonatomic,retain) UITableView *listView;
```

in .m

```
@synthesize listView = listView_;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
FWMessageCell *cell = nil;
cell = (FWMessageCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[[FWMessageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    
reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
[cell setMessage:message];
return cell;
}

- (void) dealloc {
  self.listView = nil;// my tableView
  [super dealloc];
}
```

and in the UITableViewCell class

```
- (void) dealloc {
  [message_ release], message_ = nil;
  [super dealloc];
}
```

my problem is when i navigate to back first dealloc is called but cell class dealloc is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cell = [[[FWMessageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    
reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

This means that your cell is being placed in the autorelease pool created by the Application Kit. I assume that you are using some kind of `UINavigationController` and navigate back. Your cell will only be deallocated when the pool drains. This need not happen when you navigate back. As, to when it does happen, have a look at the documentation:

> The Application Kit creates an autorelease pool on the main thread at the beginning of every cycle of the event loop, and drains it at the end, thereby releasing any autoreleased objects generated while processing an event.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: thanx for your reply.
but if i release my tableView in dealloc then [pool drain] automatically called for its subviews which are my custom cell

Comment: @chandan Even if your tableView releases its ownership of the custom cell, it will still be in the autorelease pool. The dealloc of the tableView does not mean the pool drains.

Comment: @ MadhavanRP you are right i think i have to study on tableView and autoreleasePool class reference

again thanks for your reply.